# CSS Background Image Cover property not showing on Mobile version of Safari and iphone

Tags: css, responsive-design, mobile-safari, background-image

I'm having an issue with displaying full page background images on the iphone specifically with the safari browser. I have a parallax effect for my website on the mobile version with full page image backgrounds. The background cover property of CSS3 is working fine in other mobile browsers (chrome, firefox, UC, Opera, etc) but on the iphone it doesn't show the images at all.

This is my website: http://torontoimc.com

Here is my code:

```
  <div class="slide" id="slide1" data-slide="1" data-stellar-background-ratio="0.5">

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id="first_headline">

        <div id="first_grabber">

        <h1>Because gone are the days of waking up to the Sunday paper...</h1>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>


<a class="button" data-slide="2" title=""></a>



</div><!--End Slide 1-->
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.slide {
background-attachment: fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
position: relative;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
box-shadow:inset 0px 10px 10px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);}

.wrapper {
width:90%;
height:80%;
margin: 5% 0% 0% 0%;
position: absolute;}



#slide1{


 background-image:url('news_paper_picture.jpg');
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
background-size: cover;
min-height: 100%;
min-width: 100%;}
```

I've tried the CSS fallbacks provided by CSS Tricks website. (Ref: http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/)

I'm not sure if it has anything to do with my viewport meta tag which is this:

```
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-  scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0"/>
```

I don't really want to resort to using jQuery solution from CSS tricks site as my website is already using jQuery for the parallax and I don't want to mess up the parallax.

I've read a few different similar questions on this site but most of them weren't exactly my answer.

Any suggestions would really help to solving the issue of mobile safari browser with cover property?

EDIT: I couldn't find a solution so I ended up writing different html markup for the lower end mobile version. And then using CSS to hide and display it at different media queries. It would still be good to know if someone has a solution for future reference.

Comment: It's working in the emulator I have, but you may be getting unexpected behavior from a syntax error in your `max-width: 650px` styles for `#slide1` where `background-image` should just be `background`.

Comment: Yes, I checked it on many online emulators and it seemed to work fine in all the emulators, but when I've asked 2 friends to check it on their iphone 4s, and it didn't work at all on either phones. So not sure?

Comment: Latish did you got the solution , if yes kindly share it. Thanks